# mathematical expressions in ggplot facet titles

Tags: r, ggplot2, facet-grid

I have the following task: I want to create a facet graph in which the facet titles have mathematical expressions.

This is some code:

```
rm(list=ls())
library(nlme)
library(ggplot2)
mupre<-10
sdpre<-25
n<-1000
xpre<-rnorm(n,mupre,sdpre)

############
### a function to define a variance
############
A<-matrix(c(rep(1,3),c(.2,.5,.8),c(.2,.5,.8)^2),ncol=3)
B<-c(.09,.2,.32)
A%*%solve(A,B)
X=solve(A,B)
dltf<-function(bta){c(1,bta,bta^2)%*%X}
###############
###each plot is a different simulation with different beta and delta
###############
resdf<-NULL
for(i in seq(.2,1,length.out = 10)){
  bta<-i
  dlta<-dltf(bta)
  Ec_xpost<- xpre*bta
  sdc_xpost<- xpre*dlta
  xpost<-rnorm(n,Ec_xpost,sdc_xpost)
  xpost[xpost<0]<-0
  xprepost<-data.frame(pre=xpre,post=xpost,beta=bta,delta=dlta)
  resdf<-rbind(resdf,xprepost)
  plt<-ggplot(xprepost,aes(x=xpre,y=xpost))+geom_point()+
    ggtitle(substitute(paste(beta,"=",b1,", ", delta,"=",d2),list(b1=round(bta,2),d2=round(dlta,2))))+
    geom_hline(yintercept = 0,col=2)+ geom_abline(intercept = 0, slope = 1,col=2)+
    scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-5,100))+scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-5,100))+
    labs(x="pre",y="post")
  print(plt)
}
```

This code chunk was only to illustrate that I want those titles of each graph to appear as titles in the following facet, using off course the info stored in resdf.

```
resdf$lab<-factor(resdf$beta,labels=c(expression(beta[1]),expression(beta[2]),expression(beta[3]),expression(beta[4]),
                                      expression(beta[5]),expression(beta[6]),expression(beta[7]),expression(beta[8]),
                                      expression(beta[9]),expression(beta[10])))

ggplot(resdf,aes(x=pre,y=post))+geom_point()+
  scale_x_continuous(limits = c(-5,100))+scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-5,100))+labs(x="pre",y="post")+
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0,col=2)+ geom_abline(intercept = 0, slope = 1,col=2)+
  facet_wrap( ~ lab, ncol=5,labeller = label_parsed)
```

The best I could was to put those "beta_i" labels. I appreciate any suggestions

Comment: This code seems to work fine for beta_i.  What are the actual formulas you want to use as facet labels?  What errors are you getting?

Comment: I want those used in the for loop, those used as 
`ggtitle(substitute(paste(beta,"=",b1,", ", delta,"=",d2),list(b1=round(bta,2),d2=round(dlta,2))))`

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the first plot, you don't actually need to wrap each `beta[i]` with `expression()`; `ggplot` should interpret the `plotmath` language directly from the characters.

Instead, try creating your labels into a character vector using the following format:

```
resdf$lab<-factor(resdf$beta,labels=c("list(beta[1] == 1, delta[1] == .34)", 
  "list(beta[2] == 1, delta[2] == .56)", ...))
```

Comment: Indeed it is a solution. It would be worst with increasing numbers of simulations; it should be scalable to 50 or 100 simulation for which your proposed solution would imply several code lines. I would like something more automatic if possible (sure it is)

Comment: Yes, you can use `paste` just like you did for the `ggtitle` example above to dynamically insert the appropriate beta and delta values.  Just need to end up in a format similar to what I wrote above.